# How to commit df to SQL database using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a connection to a database (using pyodbc) and I need to commit a df to a new table.  I've done this with SQL, but don't know how to do it with a df.  Any ideas on how to alter the below code to make it work for a df?

code for SQL:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd    

conn= pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=foo; UID=name; PWD=password;QUIETMODE=YES;Trusted_Connection=yes') 

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
"""
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TABLE AS 
(
SELECT ... FROM ....
)
"""
)
conn.commit()
```

I tried this code, no errors but didn't create in the database:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd    

conn= pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=foo; UID=name; PWD=password;QUIETMODE=YES;Trusted_Connection=yes') 

sheet1.to_sql(con=conn, name='new_table', schema='Schema', if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: Did you already look at the documentation of [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)? Would that be a way at least to get an idea? Esp. the SQLAlchemy engines do look promising to me, but I may be to superficially looking at it ;-)

Comment: If you are asking about this particular SQL (CREATE TABLE .. AS SELECT ...), then you don't need to commit it, because it's a DDL, which should always be followed by an implicit commit (at least all RDBMS i know [Oracle, MySQL, MS SQL] do it this way). For more generic solution look at `to_sql()` as @Dilettant has already mentioned - it will does commit for you. But I would use SQLAlchemy, instead of `pyODBC` as it's officially supported by pandas

Comment: I tried to use .to_sql, but probably used it incorrectly...  Here was what I tried:
      sheet1.to_sql(con=conn, name='new_table', schema='Schema', if_exists='replace', index=False)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `to_sql()` clearly states:

> **con : SQLAlchemy engine or DBAPI2 connection (legacy mode)**
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
>   library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.

Thus, you need to pass a SQLAlchemy engine to the `to_sql()` function to write from Pandas directly to your Teradata database.

Another way would be to dump the data to a different data structure (e.g. `to_dict()`) and then use pyODBC to perform DML statements on the database, preferably using binding variables to speed up processing.